# Where could my Fusion Cores possibly have gone to?

Tags: fallout-4

Ok, a bit annoyed; I had around 86 unused Fusion Cores in my Sanctuary Hills workshop. I was keeping them there as I don't see any real advantage in using Power Armour other than for aesthetic reasons. I hadn't checked for a while but when I'd collected a few more, I went to add them to the pile and to my utter bemusement there were no more than 41 Fusion Cores in the workshop inventory!

What could have happened to my beautiful cores? Were they stolen by the lowly settlers who are not happy with all I have given them? Is Preston getting me back for permanently sticking him in the Pillory? Maybe they have been unwittingly used for something else in the settlements?

I did try out the Gatling Laser for no more than one day, but I only used like two cores from my personal inventory.

Any ideas?

p.s. I have searched the 'net but all questions seem to be referring to cores disappearing from the personal inventory, rather than the workshop inventory.

Comment: `I don't see any real advantage in using Power Armour other than for aesthetic reasons` you should bring your power amour to a crafting station and see the options there are, some effects are not obtainable without power armours.

Comment: I can't think of any reasons for lost of fusion cores but in the future if you want a safer storage, build a room with a powered door and keep it locked unless you are accessing the container inside.

Comment: @BenOng I'm not a noob or anything, well... I've done 22 days on my save, but I'm only now really messing with the power armor, but considering it uses power to run(not sprint) I think it's a lot of cost for little gain e.g. +60 carry weight but then there's a trick to get infinite carry weight on foot anyway. The mods are good for novelty purposes but practically I think little is gained for normal combat situations. But I digress...

Comment: The extra carry weight is probably the most negligible effect of a power armour. I have had high str chars with lots of extra pocket upgrades so much so that I suffer carry weight penalty equipping power armour. What I am telling you about are the mods especially for the body piece. There effects like auto injecting stimpak and low health, stealth when crouching, and a jetpack which are effects you cannot get elsewhere. Though a only a single effect can be active as once since you can only equip 1 body piece.

Comment: There is also a mod on the head piece that highlights all target which is like a permanent variant of orange mentat. On the legs you can have an upgrade which boost sprint speed at the cost of AP. On the arms you can increase damage of unarmed attacks. And seriously, the raw defence value of the power armour is already very hard to match with normal gears.

Comment: @BenOng I'm pretty sure settlers will spawn anywhere there is a floor. I know this because they spawn inside my roofs where there is no way to enter! I thought the workshop _was_ the safest place. Do they actually steal though, because I don't think I've lost any of the stock I put out on shelves in my mini-mart. It's been there for ages too. It falls on the floor but I think it's all still there. So you know of no other reason or anything that would take FCs from the workshop? Not even something you build like the fusion generator? If it's a game error then that's even more annoying.

Comment: AFAIK settlers do not take misc/junk from the workbench, but they are known to take equipments during an attack. Ammo which fusion core are classified under is an unknown to me. I do leave some ammo in each of my settler for their weapon but I cannot confirm if they will take more from the workshop. Though I can be sure they do not spend the ammo but need at least 1 suitable for their weapon to be able to use it.

Comment: Did you perhaps left some Gatling lasers in your workbench which was taken by the settlers during an attack? Then they might have also took some fusion cores? You should check the settler's inventory to confirm that.

Comment: But the room with locked door method is confirmed to work, I deliberately disarm some settlers leaving only weapons in a locked room before an attack, they cannot take the weapons inside the room and resorted to punching, then taking up the dead raiders weapons after. I lost a couple of settlers just to test this

Comment: @BenOng Yeah, I get what you're saying about the mods but I don't see those mods as worth the hassle of worrying about how much fuel I'm using, so I have to walk everywhere and how much health I have left on the armour pieces. Maybe I should get the double fusion core time perk thing. So the cores last twice as long. I actually have the stealth crouch on one suit and that target living things mod on another. I've got like 9 suits in displays, that's why I was looking for my cores because I do want to try using them rather than just looking at them! My FC numbers have been halved though. :(

Comment: It is worth it if you anticipate a though battle ahead, or simply leave one in each settlement for use during a defence :)

Comment: Funny you should say that, I actually gave a settler a gatling laser and I think a fusion core too. I found it on him a while later and thought nothing of it. Hmmm. Wonder if that was it. Bit strange though if he did take them out of the workshop inv. Maybe it's different to normal ammo in that respect. May do a test. If I do I'l let u know.

Comment: @BenOng ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Settlers are known to steal weapons from your Workshop inventory.

For the Fusion Cores, they must have picked up a Laser Gatling gun and decide to use it.  Go attack your settlers and see who has the Laser Gatling.

Comment: You probably didn't read the comments on the OP, but I now remember taking a Gatling Laser off a settler, who (I think) I gave it to a long time before to defend the settlement, but now you got me thinking maybe I didn't _give_ it to him. I have many weapons of all sorts in the Inventory but I don't think any have ever been stolen. I think I'd have noticed. lol, I wouldn't attack the settlers, they my minions(plus, they're armed to the teeth with all the best gear! I'd prob be dead in under 3 seconds) I'll check into this stealing though, if you're right, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: OMFG I just found **94 fusion cores on Jun Long!!** ...and the Gatling Laser! I'm not sure wtf is going on now but I'm pretty sure I didn't give them to him! 94!? Basstard. I'm def gona do a test now.

Comment: You had it easy.  One of my settlers stole an Explosive Minigun and killed me with the splash damage.  It was pretty ugly.

Then another stole a glitched pistol that rapid fires multiple nukes at a time.  He ended up killing everyone in the settlement...

Comment: Another thing is the settlement inventory cannot be easily protected.  The build workshop is usually in a place that isn't barred from access, and all the stations share the same inventory.

Comment: I'm on 22 days and never experienced anything like this before. What you said made me laugh, but thats what makes this game so fun to play, it's the sudden, unexpected stuff that drops your jaw!

Comment: The inventories only share food and water and junk/material thru supply lines though, not weapons or ammo, luckily.

Answer (score 10):

## The Missing Fusion Cores Test

While I accepted [Nelson's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/324839/170898), I wasn't 100% convinced, so I decided to do my own test to see if I could finally confirm this for myself or not.

So after chatting with [Nelson](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/324807/where-could-my-fusion-cores-possibly-have-gone-to#comment462797_324839) and [BenOng](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/324807/where-could-my-fusion-cores-possibly-have-gone-to#comment462676_324807), I started searching my 34 Sanctuary Hills settlers and was quite surprised to find the Gatling Laser and ***94 fusion cores*** on the sorry-looking Jun Long...
[image]
***However***, as I do arm my settlers with all the best weaponry, I thought I'd give Jun Long the benefit of the doubt; maybe I gave him the Gatling Laser a while before and maybe I mistakenly gave him all my fusion cores instead of just one (which I have done with other items before). So I sneakily set up a fool-proof test, as I had to be **100% sure** of this crime so I can act accordingly.

So I put all my fusion cores in a wooden crate in my secure lockup (I already have a secure lockup, but I don't keep ammo, unique or rare weapons like the Gatling Laser in there for fear of them being stolen!)
[image][image]
I also placed two fusion cores in the workshop inventory, along with the Gatling Laser and as this could be a long test (and I have a bad memory), I marked these locations with the number of fusion cores and *"GAT"* for the Gatling Laser.
[image]

Finally, I took everything off Jun Long to tempt him. Let the game begin!

So I checked the inventory quite regularly, and soon my suspicion of this crime had all but diminished and I was doubting, completely, the theory that my settlers would steal from the workshop inventory. I hate to say, but I became complacent, ready to give up on the test.

Thirty six hours of gaming later; probably a month in the wasteland, while skipping through the inventory the ammo section catches my eye... what's this? The test flashes back to mind and my eyes flick to the markings on the wall *"GAT 2FC"* - but there's only one fusion core... So I sheepishly skip to the weapons section where my suspicions are confirmed; the Gatling laser is missing! THE BASTARDS!!

So, the game is back on! I run around to find Jun Long, but he still has no items whatsoever. So I ring the bell to gather my minions and start searching them one by one when I find a shocking sight, a sight that stabs through my heart like Kremvh's Tooth...
[image]
What annoys me more is that I personally gave this ghoul worker Slog immigrant the Flamer and Flamer fuel to protect himself with! The treachery! It takes all of my will to not split his skull right there (which would have also ended *me*
in around two seconds due to my heavily armed defense team).

So the test is complete. Nelson's answer is 100% confirmed. And, as there are no fusion cores or anything else missing from my secure lockup; this is indeed the place to store items that you don't want to be stolen.

So, with fusion cores and weapons now secure, there is only one thing left to do...

[image]

Comment: Wow! Absolutely wonderful post! Thanks for adding it!